Why can I see my discord js bot online but can't use it
I'm very new with javascript and I try to implement a bot for discord. I just follow the tutorial to create a bot from the website "discordjs.guide" and my bot is not responding.
I don't understand the problem here. In the administration website for discord, I checked all the intents checkbox and my code looks like this :
A ping.js file in "commands/utility" :
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};

An index.js file :
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.login(token);

When I launch my discord bot with the node command, I can see my bot turning on and become available on my discord server. When I try to type the command "/ping" message (or "!ping", "ping", ".ping", etc.), I don't have an answer.
I have the log message "Ready! Logged in as MyBot" but nothing after. The node script is still running and I don't have any error.
Thanks for your time

Where do you handle the interactions? Are you listening for the interactionCreate event somewhere?

This is all the files I got so I imagine no. This is why maybe it's not working ?
I'm following this guide : https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html

That guide is perfect, but don't forget to click on the tabs inside the code blocks (like InteractionCreate, events/interactionCreate.js, etc) and check the GitHub repo linked from the bottom of the page :)

Try putting console.log(1), console.log(2) in the part of your code that loops over the slash command folder to try and see where it stops reading since it may be a conditional error (if(...) never is true therefore the rest of the code doesn't get executed))

Deploy the commands before you start your bot, this can be done by "node [path to deploy folder]".
You should probably check over this section of the guide: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html
